# Comparing groups of Cox regression models based on the HRs

Tags: cox-model, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have 100 doctors each who evaluated 60 patients and labeled them as having disease A which kills, or not having it. 40 of them are university doctors and 60 are community doctors. I have survival data on the patients and have generated 100 survival models (Cox) - on for each doctors binary diagnosis of "has A" versus "hasn't A".

I want to know if the prognostic significance of the university doctors diagnoses are greater than the community doctors.

38/40 university doctors have prognostically significant diagnoses based on the p value <0.05

50/60 community doctors have prognostically significant diagnoses.

I wanted to compare the HR of all the university doctors diagnoses (40 HRs) to the HR of the community doctors (60 HRs) using an Wilcoxon rank sum test and see if there is a significant difference (the median HR for university doctors is 3.41 and the median HR for community doctors is 3.01).

I am not sure if this is a reasonable approach not being a statistician. May I have an expert opinion please?

HR=hazard ratio

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand but will the HR not depend on the characteristics of which patients each doctor saw?

Comment: The HR comes from the survival analysis performed using a single doctors determination if having disease A or not. I have the survival data for each patient. Therefore I have 100 cox models - one for each doctor. Make sense?

Comment: Suppose though one doctor has a group of patients with particularly poor survival and another has a group of patients with good survival. Might that not affect the HR in some way.

Comment: Ah. I see what you are saying. They all, independently reviewed the same patients.

Comment: I think I don't understand something: What did you use a cox model for? You don't seem to have any event.. If the event is diagnosis (A, not A) it's not an event really and is definitely not longitudinal in nature.

Comment: Death is the event. I have said twice that I have survival data for these patients, which is follow up time and death. These parts of the question aren't really that important. The issue is, the validity of comparing median HRs of subgroups of doctors as a means of assessing which subgroups give the most prognostically significant diagnoses.